# node.js set proxy for http,https and ws connections globally

Tags: node.js, http, https, websocket, proxy

My problem is the following:
In an app I am working on I need to use http, https and websocket connections all from behind a corporate proxy.
All of these connections are established from submodules some of them thirdparty and with no option to specify a proxy server.

My question is:
Is there a way to set a global proxy value that is honored by all submodules ?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this [global-tunnel library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/global-tunnel). It might suit your needs.

> To make all HTTP and HTTPS connections go through an outbound HTTP proxy

It may not work with websockets however.

Comment: tried this but only got an protocol  unsupported from the proxy server
sample code
var globalTunnel = require('global-tunnel');
var request = require("request");


globalTunnel.initialize({
    host: 'proxy.company.com',
    port: 8080
});

request("http://www.sitepoint.com", function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
});
globalTunnel.end();